# Android GoogleMap when network goes down

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am using `GoogleMap` instance to display user's location. Everything works fine until I shut down `wi-fi`. Application stops to respond and even `ANR` appears. Logs say that there is too much work on `UI` thread. I understand that `GoogleMap` needs network to be useful. Is there any way to catch when network goes down or do I have to make a broadcast receiver notify user and display error? 
Here is my instantiation of the map:

```
 googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

It appears to me that it is the case only when I set onLocationChangeListener to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `LocationListener` class then It overrides some methods then do your action in  `onProviderDisabled`

```
@Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
         // do your action here
        }
```

Comment: Now I get why onLocationChangeListener is not best the best practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with if network goes down, create a new java class

```
public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
  {
      ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)      
      context.getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
      NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      NetworkInfo mobNetInfo =   
      connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE );
      if ( activeNetInfo != null )
      {
          Toast.makeText( context, "Active Network Type : " +   
          activeNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
      }
      if( mobNetInfo != null )
      {
          Toast.makeText( context, "Mobile Network Type : " + 
          mobNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
      }
  }
```

}

In your AndroidManifest.xml under the "manifest" element add

```
<!-- Needed to check when the network connection changes -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Under the "application" element: in AndroidManifest.xml add

```
<receiver android:name="com.blackboard.androidtest.receiver.ConnectionChangeReceiver"
      android:label="NetworkConnection">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid creating broadcast receiver, but thanks anyway!

Comment: That is fine, I tried to help with what I know as you had queried for such requirement :)